# MySQL Load Data Infile extremely slow

Tags: mysql, load

I have searched in Google, in StackOverflow, I have tested many methods, but I really don't understand why the query is extremely slow.

I have a CSV file with this structure with 94K rows:

```
name;email;employer;city;state;born;active;group;
```

with two load data queries. One for group (with dummy columns and with name in the last) and other query to import the columns ignoring the last.

```
--- FIRST (It is running for 12 hours and did not finish yet.)
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/path/file.csv'
    REPLACE INTO TABLE group 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, name)
    SET id = NULL, active = 1;

--- SECOND (not begin because the first not ended)
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/path/file.csv'
    REPLACE INTO TABLE subscriber 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
    (name, email, employer, city, state, born, active, @dummy)
    SET id = NULL;
```

Ok, I don't have the best computer, but the file not is too large.
I have a Windows 64bits with 4GB RAM, using XAMPP;

In my.ini I have this settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
```

Please, can someone help me? Sorry my english and thank you!

**Edit**

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
    created TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    active TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT "1", 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY name_UNIQUE (name)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Smells like there is a missing index.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Are `email`, etc, also in that table??

Comment: Does `subscriber` have the same layout?

Comment: Email is used only in the second script to insert into subscriber table, ignoring the last column from the first script. The subscriber table have the same layout but the unique key is email

Comment: Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE subscriber` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`REPLACE` is `DELETE` any or all rows that match, then `INSERT` the one row.

For `REPLACE` to be useful, you need an index, preferrably `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` so that it knows what to `DELETE`.

Do you have an index on `group`; that is what the first `REPLACE` needs.  Or am I confused about the columns?

Also, ... Consider whether it would be better to use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `REPLACE`.  The semantics is similar, but different.

If those suggestions do not work, then I recommend, `LOADing` the CSV files into temp tables, then perform queries to copy the data into the 'real' tables.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have created a dynamically MyISAM table (not `TEMPORARY`) to both and insert. After I inserted into "official" table (InnoDB) using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Total: 0.944 sec for the first statement and 1.765 sec for the second

Comment: So, you are happy with those timings?  And the solution was to have a staging table, plus change from REPLACE to IODKU?